# How was Supergirl able to beat up the guards?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, supergirl

As some of us (if not all) know, Kara Zor-El and Mon-El are from close planets (are they?) hence the super powers. In the Supergirl episode where Supergirl breaks into the mother-ship to save Mon-El and Lena, she was able to defeat the guards easily. To my understanding, she shouldn't have been able to, since they are also Daxamites, having super-strength. Rhea has it. Why is that? Is it because they were on the ship all the time, thus not being exposed to the sunlight, or is there another explanation?

Comment: Because had that power form years and we are not sure how long those guards have that power. And Dexamite appear weaker then Kryptonian to me.

Comment: However, Rhea was able to beat Supergirl.

Comment: Didn't she used green kryptonite

Comment: Did she? I didn't know that. Let me watch the episode again.

Comment: In the last fight she did I think

Comment: You mean where Rhea tricked Lena into opening the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kara has super strength.  So do the Daxamites, but as is shown when Mon-El is being tested by Winn at the DEO, the Daxamite level of strength is less than the Kryptonian equivalent.  They are also missing a number of the powers Kara exhibits, including flight and freeze breath.

So Kara is stronger, and she has also trained with her sister Alex in a variety of fighting styles (in a room using small amounts of Kryptonite radiation to bring Kara down to a more human level of strength).  These facts combine to make her suitably dangerous even to (presumably) well trained soldiers/guards with a level of super strength.